# How to apply .LOOK/.CUBE (LUT) on a png in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, post-processing

I have a nodeJS script that automatically creates random .PNG images.
The idea is to add a filter after the creation process.

My designer configured this filter via a LUT (.cube or .look), the question is how to apply it to a png automatically?

I found a script from @abbath but it uses canva LUTs, which I don't have?
https://gist.github.com/kishmiryan-karlen/559c190f6c20856ee323

Thanks for your help !